# Netbeans 11 Terminal "Unable to start pty process:"

Tags: netbeans

I'm using netbeans 64 bit 11 with PHP.

When I go to Terminal, it shows "Unable to start pty process:"

I'm sure, I installed Cygwin 64 bits and I have it added to my windows path variables; C:\cygwin64\bin

Am I missing something?

It used to work in previous versions of netbeans.

Thanks.